# Type 'Observable<Service[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to force an array of products/services to accept a JSON file and read it.
However, I catch the error specified above. I don't know what to do anymore. I catch this error in product. service.ts and product.components.ts. I`m noob, please keep it simple.
**product.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Service } from './products';

export class ProductService {
    items: Serivce[] = [];

    
    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
    ) {}
    getShippingPrices(): Observable<Service> {   
        this.items = this.http.get<Service[]>('../../../../assets/shipping.json');
    }
  }
```

**product.component.ts**

```
import { Service } from './products';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {  
  service: Service[] = this.producService.getShippingPrices();
  /*[{
    name: "Элитный",
    price: 150,
    link: "http://xzzxvds.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Суперский",
    price: 300,
    link: "http://youtube.com"
  }
  ];*/

  constructor( private producService:ProductService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**products.ts**

```
export class Service
{
    name: string;
    price: number;
    link: string;
    //constructor(public name: string, public price: number, public link: string){}
}
```

**json**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Overnight",
        "price": 25,
        "link": "http://youtube.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "2-Day",
        "price": 9,
        "link": "http://youtube.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Postal",
        "price": 2,
        "link": "http://youtube.com"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**import** the **http client module** into **app module** and **import** **behavior subject** into your service.

from here you can import this service into any component and call it via shipping$ as an observable to access its data.

```
private shipping = new BehaviorSubject<[any]>([''] as any);
   public shipping$ = this.shipping.asObservable();



getShipping(){
      this.http.get('/assets/shipping.json')
        // pipe then map response -- immediately subscribe to response
        // from get data and set as subject for async functions as observable
        .pipe(map((res: any) => (res = res))).subscribe((sub: any) => {
          sub = sub;
           this.shipping.next([sub]);

        });
    }
```